# What is “Error -2” on Zapier

Tags: zapier

I am trying to set up a zap on zapier.com with a webhook to my own site. However, I am getting the following error:

> Bargle. We hit an error creating a post. :-( Error:
>   -2

I can't seem to find a reference to -2 in relation to Zapier on Google.

I tested my URL on my site and it executes without error.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had entered my URL without `http://` in front of it.

Works fine as long as I put `http://` in front of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem turned out to be that my copy and paste of the URL into Zapier had white space in front of it.

Pretty hard to see unless you are looking for it.

I wish Zapier did an auto `trim()`, but meanwhile, if this is happening to you check for whitespace.